# How to obtain the array element as string

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a JSON result in my copy job which like this:

```json
{
    "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Company 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Company 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Company 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to store the the result in a table with one row per company, and it works if I have a table containing all the fields, I have "Collection reference" set to `$['data']` and I can then map `['id']` to "id" and so forth.

But I'd like to store the whole:

```json
{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Company 1"
}
```

in a table field, because there are lots of custom fields I will not be able to map in ADF copy activity. Is there a way to reference the JSON array element? I'd be surprised if it's not possible, because I can already reference the fields within the element as `$['data']['id']` .

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- Use web activity to make a call to your REST API and iterate through the response returned (data property).
- I have stored your response in a look up and iterated through `data` property for demonstration.
- Inside for each, I have used an `append variable` activity with the following dynamic content:

```
'@{string(item())}'
```

[image]

- Now I have used a copy data activity to store the data in a csv file as additional column. I have taken a file as shown below as my source (header and a row):

[image]

- Now, add an additional column called `data` with value as shown below:

```
@join(variables('demo'),'
')
```

- Configure your sink (delimited text) as shown in the below image:

[image]

- In mapping, keep only the column that we created above and delete the rest (delete `id` in the below).

[image]

- When I write this file, I get the resulting csv file as shown in the below image (array element as string):

[image]

- You can read the above file with quote character as single quote and then configure this data to your sink accordingly. Each of the element would be written as string.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it does seem like a big  workaround. I was hoping it's just a matter of putting the right syntax, because I can retrieve the whole JSON result, I can retrieve specific attributes and subattributes and subentities of array element... but I cannot retrieve the element itself. So far, I was putting the whole result in SQL DB and then using the CROSS APPLY to iterate through the elements, I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution :)

Comment: Hey @Mara, since each element of the array is an object, it needs to be converted to string. Can you state again what the requirement is?

Comment: I'm retreiving data from REST API, and data is often served as Array or elements. Since we have custom fields (attributes) that often change, I'd like to store each array element as an object in my database and deal with custom fields in DB, not in ADF (mapping). The way I do it now is I store the whole resultset in DB, and I perform some CROSSAPPLY/JOIN on the single object and I get a DB result with elements I need which I can then store as I prefer. It's very little code, but it's done on DB side.

Comment: And my preference would be to split the array on ADF side, but it seems to be even much more code/effort. I was hoping ADF copy activity would be able to split the array, but it obviously isn't. At least not for REST API, I know data flow solution would work for some other type of source.